# Showing alert message in VB.NET

Tags: asp.net, alert

In my server side code, I need to display an alert message and stop the execution of the page when a certain condition is satisfied. The execution stops, but I am not getting the alert message. What am I missing? My code goes like this.

```
Try
        If txtAmtRequested.Text > Val(HiddenTotalFeeAmount.Value) Then
            ScriptManager.RegisterClientScriptBlock(Me, GetType(Page), UniqueID,
            "javascript:alert('Total Fee Amount set for this student is - '" & HiddenTotalFeeAmount.Value & "'... Enter Concession Amount lesser than this one..!')", True)
                Exit Function
            End If
        Catch ex As Exception

        End Try
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
Try
    If txtAmtRequested.Text > Val(HiddenTotalFeeAmount.Value) Then
        ScriptManager.RegisterClientScriptBlock(Me, GetType(Page), UniqueID,
        "javascript:alert('Total Fee Amount set for this student is - " & HiddenTotalFeeAmount.Value & "... Enter Concession Amount lesser than the..!');", True)
            Exit Function
        End If
    Catch ex As Exception

    End Try
```

You ended the string in javascript when inserting your value, resulting in this javascript:

```
javascript:alert('Total Fee Amount set for this student is - ' <Value> '... Enter Concession Amount lesser than the..!');
```

Instead of this you have to insert the value directly into the string, or add "+" to concat the strings:

```
 javascript:alert('Total Fee Amount set for this student is - <Value> ... Enter Concession Amount lesser than the..!');
```

or

```
javascript:alert('Total Fee Amount set for this student is - ' + <Value> + '... Enter Concession Amount lesser than the..!');
```